# Использование AlarmManager

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно написать небольшое приложение - в определенный момент времени отправляется какое-либо смс сообщение на какой-либо номер телефона.
Я поняла что можно использовать AlarmManager и в определенное время запустится Activity, которая и выполнит отправку смс на указанный номер. Но я не знаю как запрограммировать чтобы каждый раз в эту Activity отправлять новые данные.
Помогите, пожалуйста, с реализацией.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартным способом отправки данных в `Activity` является через `Intent.putExtra()` с извлечением на стороне `Activity` через `Intent.getExtra()`

Comment: Это я знаю. Каждый раз в Activity должны новые данные отправляться именно в этом проблема.

Comment: @Asy если у вас есть набор данных которые по очереди (какими то блоками) нужно отправлять, вы можете сложить их в БД или какой то файл и в момент когда нужно отправить данные - берете их с БД и отправляете.